# Tornar um input obrigatorio com base no input anterior

Tags: angular, typescript, formulário, validação

Galera que puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Eu tenho alguns campos reativos no meu código, eles se tornam obrigatorios ou não com base no campo anterior, meu codigo esta assim

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
        <msp-input-text id="nome" label="Qual é o nome da pessoa?" tooltip="teste" tooltip="teste"></msp-input-text>
      </div>

      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
        <msp-input-text id="nome-social" label="Possui nome social? se sim, qual?" tooltip="teste" tooltip="teste"></msp-input-text>
      </div>
```

Ao informar o **Nome**, o campo **Nome-social** se torna obrigatorio. Caso o usuario não informe o ***Nome***, o campo ***Nome-social*** ficara livre de validações

até então tinha montando algo assim

```
private setRequiredAndUpdateValidate(stringFormName: string[], group?: string) {
if (group) {
  stringFormName.forEach(formName => {
    this.form
      .get(group)
      .get(formName)
      .setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.form
      .get(group)
      .get(formName)
      .updateValueAndValidity();
  });
} else {
  stringFormName.forEach(formName => {
    this.form.get(formName).setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.form.get(formName).updateValueAndValidity();
  });
}
```

}

para ai montar uma validação no campo, segue abaixo:

```
private verificaVeioPlantao() {
this.form.get('nome').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  if (val) {
    this.setRequiredAndUpdateValidate(['nome-social'], 'identidade');
  } else {
    this.clearValidatorsAndUpdateValidate([nome-social'], 'identidade');
  }
});
```

}

Existe uma forma de simplificar isso?

Estava pensando em algo assim ====>

```
onValidator(event: any): void {
if (this.form.get('nome').value === 'S') {
  this.form.controls['nome-social'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
} else {
  this.form.controls['nome-social'].clearValidators();
}
```

}

Comment: Essa sua segunda solução está bem melhor, só não esquece de usar o operador takeUntil pra evitar memory leaks

Comment: Mas para realizar a segunda opção, tive que implementar a primeira, adicionei um outro metodo acima, mas não esta funcionando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há uma possibilidade de você checar se o campo nome está preenchido, e caso esteja preenchido, o outro campo seja obrigatório, existem libs para isto, que são libs de validação de schemas, por exemplo, em Javascript e NodeJS, temos o Yup, e nele tem como fazer uma verificação de campos, vou colocar um código abaixo para você ver.

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string(),
  email: Yup.string().email(),
  oldPassword: Yup.string().min(6),
  password: Yup.string()
    .min(6).when('oldPassword', (oldPassword, field) => 
      oldPassword ? field.required() : field),
  confirmPassword: Yup.string().when('password', (password, field) =>
    password ? field.required().oneOf([Yup.ref('password')]) : field),
});
```

Neste código ele diz que o confirmPassword ele é obrigatório quando o password é preenchido. E abaixo segue um link que talvez possa te ajudar bastante 
https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-4-forms-validation